# How to display a message in-place of an api when it returns "No-Content"

Tags: html, api

I have a js script that gets the now_playing data for a web radio and then displays it as an element on my custom radio html page. However I was wondering how I would go about displaying a message on that element on the html page when the api returns no-content instead of just it displaying nothing.

API on swagger: https://derrick.xonosho.st/static/api/index.html

JS script:

```
$.getJSON(
       "https://derrick.xonosho.st/api/nowplaying/1",
       function (data) {
         // artist name, song title, URL album
        var song_title = data["now_playing"]["song"]["title"];
        var artist_name = data["now_playing"]["song"]["artist"];
        var album_URL = data["now_playing"]["song"]["art"];
        var dj_name = data["now_playing"]["streamer"];

        $(".disk").css("background-image", `url("${album_URL}")`);
        $("#title").html(
        `${song_title}`
        );
        $("#artist").html(
        `${artist_name}`
         );
         $("#dj").html(
         `${dj_name} is Live!`
         );
       }
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.done` method to find the status:

```js
$.getJSON(
  "https://derrick.xonosho.st/api/nowplaying/1",
  function(data) {
    // artist name, song title, URL album
    var song_title = data["now_playing"]["song"]["title"];
    var artist_name = data["now_playing"]["song"]["artist"];
    var album_URL = data["now_playing"]["song"]["art"];
    var dj_name = data["now_playing"]["streamer"];

    $(".disk").css("background-image", `url("${album_URL}")`);
    $("#title").html(
      `${song_title}`
    );
    $("#artist").html(
      `${artist_name}`
    );
    $("#dj").html(
      `${dj_name} is Live!`
    );
  }
).done(function(...args){
  var response = args[2];
  if(response.status === 204){
    // Show empty message
  }
});
```

Comment: After trying what you suggested, I put "$("#dj").html(`AutoDJ is Live!`);" where you labelled empty message in the script but I am still getting the same thing, nothing being shown

Comment: Try logging the `response` and see what it is.

Comment: When logging the response nothing is shown and its just blank.